# Access code behind data into .aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have one record from sql database into code behind.
I want to use its fields into entire .aspx page.
What should i do?
My code is like:
default.aspx.cs

```
public partial class view_diamond : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public string id; 
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Label1.Text = Request.QueryString["diamond_id"];   
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            showData();
        }
    }
    protected void showData()
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["JemfindConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        conn.Open();
        id = Request.QueryString["diamond_id"];  

        string sqlSelect = "SELECT * FROM diamond_detail WHERE final_diamond_id="+id;
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlSelect, conn);

        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);

        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

I want to use different fields in different controls of .aspx page.
Controls like:
default.aspx

```
<asp:Label ID="diamond_carat_lbl" CssClass="diamond_carat_lbl" runat="server" Text=' ' ></asp:Label>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "I want to use its fields into entire .aspx page."? Please, give us a little bit more context.

Comment: Means I don't want to bind data table with any particular control like repeater. I want to use fields with any control of .aspx page.

Comment: There are a bunch of databound controls for this. Repeater, datalist, datagrid, formview to name a few. Check the documentation (this is well documented all over the place, I'd start with www.asp.net) and pick the one you think best suits your needs. Microsoft has a learning ASP site with tutorials on these controls.

Answer (score 1):

So you might want to bind different values of your query result to some labels or textboxes? That should work. What's preventing you from doing that in code behind?

By the way, you should wrap your `SqlConnection` in a [using statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) since it implements [IDisposable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable(v=vs.110).aspx). That makes sure your connection gets disposed of properly, even if there's an error. And your code is vulnerable to [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks since you didn't parameterize your queries.

```
id = Request.QueryString["diamond_id"]; //Probably should use String.IsNullOrEmpty and display a message to the client if the parameter isn't here
var cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM diamond_detail WHERE final_diamond_id=@id");
cmd.Paramaters.AddWithValue("id", id);
var dt = new DataTable();
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["JemfindConnectionString"].ConnectionString));
{
    cmd.Connection = conn;
    conn.Open();  
    dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader()); //We eliminated the SqlDataAdapter
}
var record = dt.AsEnumerable().Single(); //retrieve one DataRow from DataTable
diamond_carat_lbl.Text = record.Field<string>("carats"); //Get the field called carats
diamond_name_lbl.Text = record.Field<string>("name");
```